# No spring/inertia in horizontal scrolling in Finder on M1 Mac in MacOS Monterey

Tags: finder, apple-silicon, macos, monterey

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.0.1 with M1 MacBook Pro 14". The horizontal scrolling in Finder is choppy. It does not have the normal spring/inertia, the motion stops immediately when I lift fingers from the track pad. Is there a fix for it?

[image: Horizontal scrolling has no inertia on Monterey/M1 Mac]

Comment: Still exists in 12.1 !

Comment: This issue occurs on our Intel iMacs (2017-2019). Still occurs on 12.1 for all of our iMacs.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After about 8 hours of use, the issue has returned on macOS Monterey. I am continuing to investigate this issue and will update my answer if I can find what caused the temporary fix.

---

<strike>Testing on a number of devices shows this scrolling issue being fixed on macOS 12.2 Monterey.</strike>

Answer (score -1):

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Accessibility` -> `Mouse & Trackpad` -> <kbd>Trackpad Options...</kbd> (or <kbd>Mouse Options...</kbd>.
Turn on `Scrolling with inertia`.

Comment: The option was already enabled, and it does not solve the problem for me.